# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - Unable to work on any reports

Tags: reporting

It was all working fine in my Trailhead playground but suddenly Im getting below error while working on Reports. Neither able to create any Report using New Report under Reports Tab nor edit any existing report. I was working on superbadge and all of sudden getting this error. Tried other TPs but same error. Not sure how to proceed further. Any help is appreciated.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Object report.lightningReport-app.chunk.82c3359a56564251e989.js:1

Comment: Have you checked if there is an outage or an issue on the instance for your Salesforce org, You can go to https://status.salesforce.com/ and check if there is a maintenance issue going on or an issue has been reported.

Comment: The best resource for Trailhead challenge questions [is here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/help).  Choose "Share Your Feedback" to open a case with Salesforce over technical issues, or "Connect with the Community" to post questions about completing challenges.